# File associate by MIME subtype / extension

Tags: mint, mime-type, nemo, file-association

I'm writing files in markdown format using the markdown editor Remarkable and I name these files with the extension *.md. I'd like to associate the these files with Remarkable but if I do so the result is that any plain text file `text/plain` is associated with Remarkable which is not what I want.

If I issue `metype myTextFile.md` I get `text/markdown` so I would have expected that I could associate by the subtype.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. make right click on any `*.md` file in file-manager,
2. select *Open with*,
3. select *Other application*,
4. select *Remarkable* from this list,
5. check *Remember this application for "Markdown document" files*

If it does not work - you can edit *~/.config/mimeapps.list* by hand:

Add (or change existing) line

```
text/markdown=remarkable.desktop;
```

to the section

```
[Added Associations]
```